# Openssl C++ get expiry date

Tags: c++, openssl, x509certificate

What is the function that I should use to get the x509 certificate expiry date? I will first check the validity of the certificate. If it has expired, I need to get the expiry date of the certificate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit: You should be doing the below after using X509_get_notAfter and X509_get_notBefore as answered previously by "Forever".

To convert the `ASN1_TIME` you can use `ASN1_TIME_print()` routine declared in asn1.h.

This would do the job:

```
BIO *bio;
int write = 0;
bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
if (bio) {
    if (ASN1_TIME_print(bio, tm))
        write = BIO_read(bio, buf, len-1);
    BIO_free(bio);
}
buf[write]='\0';
return write;
```

Comment: yes.. allocate enough memory to hold a string with format "YYMMDDHHMMSS" or maybe a little more than that to be safe..

Comment: How do I achieve this if I have no BIO? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235368/asn1-time-print-functionality-without-bio

Comment: Thanks for this! Found this after spending two days banging my head against the wall on this thing.
I have put together a gist here https://gist.github.com/raakasf/1853039e7c4dd19fbde397e9d7ccc83c summing up this answer and another related one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23407376/testing-x509-certificate-expiry-date-with-c

Answer (score 7):

I think you should use this.

```
#define     X509_get_notBefore(x) ((x)->cert_info->validity->notBefore)
#define     X509_get_notAfter(x) ((x)->cert_info->validity->notAfter)
```

Look at this for example. Examples use this macro.

http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/X509_STORE_CTX_set_verify_cb.html

Comment: what do they return? Dont they just test whether the current certificate if valid not before or not after the current date?

Comment: @PrasanthMadhavan They returns ANS1_TIME*. Look at x509.h header.

Comment: Note that these macros expect that `x` is of type `X509 *`.

Comment: These macros are no longer valid in 1.1.0h.  Would be nice if you updated for modern API.
 const ASN1_TIME *before = X509_get0_notBefore( x509 );
 const ASN1_TIME *after = X509_get0_notAfter( x509 );