# ASN1_TIME_print functionality without BIO?

Tags: c, openssl

As described in this question: [Openssl C++ get expiry date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683021/openssl-c-get-expiry-date), there is the possibility to write an ASN1 time into a BIO buffer and then read it back into a custom buffer `buf`:

```
BIO *bio;
int write = 0;
bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
if (bio) {
  if (ASN1_TIME_print(bio, tm))
    write = BIO_read(bio, buf, len-1);
  BIO_free(bio);
}
buf[write]='\0';
return write;
```

How could this be achieved without using BIO at all? The `ASN1_TIME_print` function is only present when `OPENSSL_NO_BIO` is not defined. Is there a way to write the time directly into a given buffer?

Answer (score 4):

You can try the sample code below. It doesn't use BIO, but should give you the same output as the OP's example. If you don't trust the ASN1_TIME string, you'll want to add some error checking for:

- notBefore->data is > 10 chars
- each char value is between '0' and '9'
- values for year, month, day, hour, minute, second
- type

You should test for the type (i.e. UTC), if you expect multiple types.

You should also test whether or not the date/time is GMT and add that to the string if you want the output to match exactly as if using BIOs. see:
openssl/crypto/asn1/t_x509.c - ASN1_UTCTIME_print or ASN1_GENERALIZEDTIME_print

---

```
ASN1_TIME* notBefore = NULL;
int len = 32;
char buf[len];
struct tm tm_time;

notBefore = X509_get_notBefore(x509_cert);

// Format ASN1_TIME  with type UTC into a tm struct
if(notBefore->type == V_ASN1_UTCTIME){
    strptime((const char*)notBefore->data, "%y%m%d%H%M%SZ" , &tm_time);
    strftime(buf, sizeof(char) * len, "%h %d %H:%M:%S %Y", &tm_time);
}

// Format ASN1_TIME with type "Generalized" into a tm struct
if(notBefore->type == V_ASN1_GENERALIZEDTIME){
     // I didn't look this format up, but it shouldn't be too difficult
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be possible, at least in terms of writing the time directly into a given buffer -- but you'll still need to use BIOs.

Ideally, `BIO_new_mem_buf` would suit, given that it creates an in-memory BIO using a given buffer as the source.  Unfortunately, that function treats the given buffer as *read-only*, which is not what we want.  However, we can create our own function (let's call it `BIO_new_mem_buf2`), based on the `BIO_new_mem_buf` [source code](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/bio/bss_mem.c#L111):

```
BIO *BIO_new_mem_buf2(void *buf, int len)
{
    BIO *ret;
    BUF_MEM *b;
    size_t sz;

    if (!buf) {
        BIOerr(BIO_F_BIO_NEW_MEM_BUF, BIO_R_NULL_PARAMETER);
        return NULL;
    }
    sz = (size_t)len;
    if (!(ret = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem())))
        return NULL;
    b = (BUF_MEM *)ret->ptr;
    b->data = buf;
    b->length = sz;
    b->max = sz;
    return ret;
}
```

This is just like `BIO_new_mem_buf`, *except* that *a)* the `len` argument **must** indicate the size of the given buffer, and *b)* the BIO is *not* marked "readonly".

With the above, you should now be able to call:

```
ASN1_TIME_print(bio, tm)
```

and have the time appear in your given buffer.

*Note* that I have not tested the above code, so YMMV.  Hope this helps!