# Testing X509 Certificate Expiry date with C

Tags: c, cryptography, openssl

How can I programaticlaly test if a X509 ?* certificate is expired or not ?
Is their a direct crypto api ?
or I have to get the not_after time and check it manually in my code ?

Comment: In what language do you want to programmatically test?

Comment: C , and I was searching look like I have to do time_t now; X509_cmp_time(cert, &now)

Comment: I guess you may want to check the code of the openssl verify command, which does check the validity of the final certificate.

Comment: Did you get this to work? For some reason when I used the C code mentioned below it's giving me a not after date in the past. I have confirmed using openssl cli that the cert expires in future and I even use it in my actual app so the cert is valid for sure. This should be easier, have spent entire day and still nowhere with this!

Comment: Nvm, here's gist that shows how to get this to work: https://gist.github.com/raakasf/1853039e7c4dd19fbde397e9d7ccc83c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't say which language so I was summing them up anyway:

**php**

```
$data = openssl_x509_parse(file_get_contents('/path/to/cert.crt'));

$validFrom = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $data['validFrom_time_t']);
$validTo = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $data['validTo_time_t']);
```

**Java [X509Certificate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html)**

```
InputStream inStream = null;

 try (InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream("fileName-of-cert")) {
     CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
     X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(inStream);

     // check if valid on specific date (now set for today)
     cert.checkValidity(new Date());
     // Date nBefore = cert.getNotBefore();
     // Date nAfter = cert.getNotAfter();
 }
```

**C++**

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Security::Cryptography::X509Certificates;
int main()
{

   // The path to the certificate.
   String^ Certificate = "Certificate.cer";

   // Load the certificate into an X509Certificate object.
   X509Certificate^ cert = X509Certificate::CreateFromCertFile( Certificate );

   // Get the value.
   String^ results = cert->GetExpirationDateString();

   // Display the value to the console.
   Console::WriteLine( results );
}
```

**C**

```
X509 *x
time_t *ptime;
i=X509_cmp_time(X509_get_notBefore(x), ptime);
i=X509_cmp_time(X509_get_notAfter(x), ptime);
```

Comment: Is it possible that you mistook operator `^` for `&` in the C++ snippet?

Comment: Also, that snippet relies on .NET classes. It wouldn't hurt to mention it.

Comment: ^ is an equivalent to * in c++/CLI. handle to a reference pointer

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use:

```
result=X509_cmp_time(X509_get_notBefore(cert), ptime);
```

and

```
result=X509_cmp_time(X509_get_notAfter(cert), ptime);
```

using OpenSSL. I'm not sure if you can get it less "manual" than that.

Comment: what is ptime here ? is it a openssl variable ? of time_t

Comment: Yep, `time_t` representing the current time (or at least the time you want to validate against).

Comment: `time_t now;time(&now);` and I should pass now pointer to time_t in X509 cmp API, I guess only notAfter is OK to check whether its expired or not right?

Comment: Validity is measured using both `notBefore` and `notAfter`, expiration is measured using just `notAfter`, yes. Of course, you should also use CLR or OCSP where available.

Comment: CLR -> CRL for certificate revocation list in above comment, of course.